# ViewBag does not exist in current context in MVC 6 Beta 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get an MVC 6 beta 8 website up and running. The project contains Web controllers as well as api controllers. The api and web controllers are all working fine. But when using @ViewBag in the views gives the "ViewBag does not exist in the current context". The only thing in the entire solution that does not work are the views.

Anyone encountered a similar problem and is possible to point me into a certain direction or provide a solution?

Comment: Could you please share a bit more? What's the template you started with? What have you done so far to get to that point? Have you installed the latest Beta8 tooling? Have you ran `dnvm upgrade`?

Comment: I started with an empty ASP.NET 5 preview template and created controllers and views. Up until that point I had no problem. After I installed Entity Framework 7 I started noticing these problem. I installed the latest beta8 tooling and already did a dnvm upgrade. This didn't help.

Comment: Can you amend your question to include your view and the controller action which populates the viewbag?

Comment: public class AppController : Controller  
    {  
        // GET: /<controller>/  
        public IActionResult Index()  
        {  
            return View();  
        }  
    }  
  
In the view I Index.cshtml I just added the command  
@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";  
}

Comment: The services configured in your startup class might also help

Comment: I only have these services: services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                {
                    opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                });

            services.AddLogging();

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem.

I went to the **project.json** file in my solution and add this line of code

**"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final"**
or **"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0"**

Sometimes we accidentally add wrong package name in the project.json file; always make sure you add the right thing! I prefer typing it out so I know exactly what I need to add. Quick Action (Ctrl + .) sometimes adds sub file reference (Not in all case; rarely).

I hope I was helpful.

Comment: By the way I was using ASP.NET Core (.NET Core) with MVC 6 when I faced this error.

Answer (score 1):

It is called `ViewData` now.

To set in a controller

```
ViewData["Message"] = "fibble";
```

To read in your view

```
@ViewData["Message"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar problem in my app.

I deleted the relevant folder under the view section and added the view page from controller with add view way.

The problem was fixed.